# Refactor two similar functions into one?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this very simple sign up/log in program for learning purpose, and it works. But it feels like I have code that repeats itself. The must obvious is the check functions.

My question is, should I refactor those two so they become one or is it better to keep them seperate?

```
def signUp():
    username = input("Give me a username: ")

    if checkUser(username) == True:
        print("You are already registrered, please log in with your password.")
    else:
        password = input("Also give me a password: ")
        with open("sign-up.csv", "a", newline="") as file:
            writer = csv.writer(
                file, delimiter=",", quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL
            )
            writer.writerow([username, password])
            print("You are now signed up. Please log in with your credentials.")


def logIn():
    username = input("Give me your username: ")
    password = input("Also give me your password: ")
    if checkPassword(username, password) == True:
        print("Welcome, you are now logged in.")
    else:
        print("Username or password is incorrect please try again.")


def checkUser(username):
    with open("sign-up.csv", "r") as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        myList = dict(reader)
        if username in myList:
            return True
        else:
            return False


def checkPassword(username, password):
    with open("sign-up.csv", "r") as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        myList = dict(reader)
        if username in myList and password == myList[username]:
            return True
        else:
            return False


def get_user_choice():
    print("\n[1] Sign up")
    print("[2] Log in")
    print("[q] Quit")

    return input("What would you like to do? ")


choice = ""
while choice != "q":
    choice = get_user_choice()
    if choice == "1":
        signUp()
    elif choice == "2":
        logIn()
    elif choice == "q":
        print("Welcome back some other day")
    else:
        print("That choice doesn't exists")
```

Comment: Never ever store unencrypted passwords. Not even for learning purposes ;)

Comment: @CDJB That function checks both the username and password. I also only want to check the username.

Comment: @Dschoni I know, not really passwords that gets saved though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first obvious factorisation is the common part of both functions - the part tha reads the csv file into a dict:

```
def read_users():
    with open("sign-up.csv", "r") as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        return dict(reader)
```

Then you can rewrite check_user and check_password with this function:

```
def check_user(username):
    users = read_users()
    return username in users


def check_password(username, password):
    users = read_users()
    # make sure we work correctly even if
    # someone passes `None` as password
    _notfound = object()
    return users.get(username, _notfound) == password
```

FWIW, those functions would be better named as (resp.) 'user_exists' and 'authenticate'

Also, you may want to factor out the part that's writing to the csv file - not to reduce code duplication, but to better separate the UI / domain / persistance layers.

```
def add_user(username, password):
     with open("sign-up.csv", "a", newline="") as file:
         writer = csv.writer(
           file, delimiter=",", quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL

         writer.writerow([username, password])


def sign_up():
    username = input("Give me a username: ")

    # note how good naming makes code much more explicit
    if user_exists(username):
        print("You are already registrered, please log in with your password.")
        return # no need to go further

    password = input("Also give me a password: ")    
    add_user(username, password)



def log_in():
    username = input("Give me your username: ")
    password = input("Also give me your password: ")
    if authenticate(username, password):
        print("Welcome, you are now logged in.")
        return

    # oops...
    print("Username or password is incorrect please try again.")
```

Next step would be to replace the `input()` calls by dedicated `ask_username()` and `ask_password()` functions that will validate the user's input. First write them as simply as possible, then find out the common part(s) and see if you can factor them out.

Note that I renamed your functions in all_lower - this is [the official coding convention](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), and Python users tend to strongly adhere to the official coding conventions.

Also note that I removed the useless `== True` tests. In Python, any expression resolves to an object (in the case of a function call, to the object returned by the function), and every object has a boolean value, so `if someexpression == True:` is redundant at best. FWIW this is also part of pep8 (official coding conventions). And finally, when you find yourself writing something like:

```
if someexperession:
   return True
else:
   return False
```

You can just simplify it to

```
return someexpression
```

Answer (score 2):

Function `checkUser` is checking if a username is already present in the csv file. This would happen at signup. The function `checkPassword` is used when the user is signing in. These functions should stay seperate since they do dramaticly different things with different levels of security concerns. They also expect input based on where the user is in the procces of signup/login. Meaning when you write a function that does both like `doBoth(username, password)` you have to call this function with a null when you wanna use it at the signup fase in the application `doBoth(username, null)` since password is never known at signup.

Comment: That makes alot of sense. Maybe some times it is better to keep things seperate even if they do share some common code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def checkBoth(username, password):
    with open("sign-up.csv", "r") as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        myList = dict(reader)
        if username in myList:
            u = True
            if password == myList[username]:
                p = True
            else:
                p = False
        else:
            u = False
            p = False

        return (u,p)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def checkPassword(username, password):
out = [False, False]
    with open("sign-up.csv", "r") as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        myList = dict(reader)
        if username in myList:
            out[0] = True
            if password == myList[username]:
                out[1] = True
    return out
```

and then having a check what is true on the out.